# Cypress.io: How to read XML File and assign the contents to cy.request(body)

Tags: cypress

For one of my web service testing, I need to read an xml file and assign the contents of the same to cy.request body.
How can I achieve this?
I tried the below method and was not able to successfully pass the XML to the body.
Please let me know.

eg:

```
cy.readFile('Desktop/Testing/W1.xml')
.then(text1 => {
console.log(text1);
  cy
  .request({
       url: 'my URL',
       method: 'POST',
       body: {text1},
       headers: {
         'Authorization':'Basic ........',
         'content-type': 'application/......-v1.0+xml',
         'Accept':'application/...v1.0+json,application/....-v1.0+json'
       }
   })
.then((response) => {
    assert.equal(response.status, 200, "status was 200");
    cy.log("Response Body",response.body);
    console.log("Response Body",response.body);
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest something like this:

Prepare function for fetching XML

```js
function fetchXML(text) {
  return cy.request({
    url: 'my URL',
    method: 'POST',
    body: text,
    headers: { ... }
  })
}
```

Then call `readFile` and pass to promise callback result

```js
cy
  .readFile('Desktop/Testing/W1.xml')
  .then(text => fetchXML(text)) // or just .then(fetchXML)
  .then(responseFromXML => { ... })
```

and i second callback you can use response from XML fetch

Link to docs about `Cypress.Promise` [LINK](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Waiting-for-Promises)

Comment: Glad to help. Could you approve my answer? To be more visible for other users